# Why would I want to return a json object with a custom status field and message?

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning node and express and I noticed some tutorials like to send a response that looks like this:

```
{status: “Success”, message: “custom message”, response: {actual response object}}
```

My question is, what is the point of adding the extra status and message fields? Why not just return the response object by itself?

Comment: It’s a design decision and the “why” will be entirely dependent on your application’s architecture and your specific requirements. A Boolean “success” value can make client-side logic much easier to work with (it’s much less complex than having to parse the object somewhat extensively to understand if the request was handled by the server as expected), and a string `message` can be used to inform end users, intermediary logging/telemetry systems, etc. of error/exception conditions for monitoring and further decisioning.

Comment: In any case, this question reads a bit too opinion-based to be a good fit for Stack Overflow’s Q&A; such questions are considered off-topic here. See what’s on-topic for us here by visiting the [help/on-topic].

Comment: There is no objective answer for this, it's not like "because of X you should do Y but when there's Z you should do A", it depends on how you're sending and recieving the data, it depends on what you're using this data for, it depends on who is using this data, it depends on how you're processing this data along with many many other factors

Comment: Yow broh. What do you expect for them 5 dollars you paid. You should NOT use that and definitely it is not a good/best practice, actually it is inefficient. The more content you send, the more bytes needed, the more bandwidth use, the bigger your cloud providers bill gets. You can just do `res.sendStatus(201)` and on the client you can use the build in property ✅ `response.ok` if true then some … else …

Answer (score -1):

The simple reason is convenience. It sends a clear message to the client about the `status` of the request and what message to display based on that `status`. Its just a good programming practice that helps to structure your code base on how to handle errors from requests in the client side.